# Can't change the size of custom RatingBar

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, ratingbar

I am trying to make custom RatingBar for my android app in which i can change the default size and color of RatingBar. For this purpose i have written styles  for **CustomRatingBar** like this:

```
<style name="CustomRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/custom_ratingbar</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">25dp</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">25dp</item>
</style>
```

But the size is not changed rather it shrinks the rating bar like this:
[image]

Drawable files are : [custom_ratingbar.xml](http://pastebin.com/ebCLikfz), [custom_ratingbar_empty](http://pastebin.com/ZkyZ0UrY), [custom_ratingbar_filled](http://pastebin.com/NaYqxiMt)

In my xml, **RatingBar** looks like below:

```
         <RatingBar
                    android:id="@+id/RatingBar"
                    style="@style/CustomRatingBar"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:isIndicator="true"
                    android:numStars="5" />
```

How can i change the star size of the rating bar without shrinking it?

Comment: Use: `style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"`

Comment: what is the size of icon are you using? Used bigger icon like 48x48 or 50x50 and keep in xxhdpi folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this ,

custom rating bar style using android’s ratingBar small style.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="CustomRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar" >
 <item name="android:numStars">5</item>
 <item name="android:rating">4.5</item>
 <item name="android:stepSize">0.5</item>
 <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
 <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
 <item name="android:paddingBottom">44dip</item>
 <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">4dip</item>
 <item name="android:layout_marginTop">4dip</item>
```

Check [example.](http://android-helper.blogspot.in/2011/06/android-custom-ratingbar-example.html) for the same.

Other solution is :

Android won't scale a rating bar icons. When you decrease the minHeight and maxHeight android will always crop the icons as shown on the picture. There seems to be the only one solution is to provide your own icons for stars with the desired dimensions and set the minHeight and maxHeight to the size of the icons.

Comment: It is giving some space in bottom but the size of the star are not changing.

Comment: I have followed the example tutorial for making custom ratingBar.

Comment: i have tried that exaple and it worked so i provided that link @pialkanti

Answer (score 5):

Just add below lines to your ratingBar in xml layout

```
    android:scaleX="0.5"
    android:scaleY="0.5"
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same issue and even though this question is very old, I hope this will help someone who comes across this kind of scenario.

To increase the size of the stars in the rating bar we need to use android:scaleX and android:scaleY.

Please refer to the following example:

```
<RatingBar
android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
android:numStars="5"
android:rating="4"
android:isIndicator="true"
android:scaleX=".5"
android:scaleY=".5"
android:transformPivotX="0dp"
android:transformPivotY="0dp"
android:layout_marginBottom="-26dp"
android:layout_marginRight="-100dp"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:theme="@style/FoursquareReviewRating"/>
```

Also, you can find more details at https://en.proft.me/2017/06/18/decorating-ratingbar-android/

Answer (score 0):

```
<..
 android:scaleX=".6"
 android:scaleY=".6"
 //to avoid the unnecessary space
 android:transformPivotX="0dp"
 ../>
```