# Custom RatingBar

Tags: android, ratingbar

I stack with very annoing problem, I want to add custom drawable to my RatingBar widget, I followed [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800657/how-to-create-custom-ratings-bar-in-android) [examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221909/cant-change-the-size-of-custom-ratingbar) how to do it:

1) I created my own style, set `minHeight=16dip` and `maxHeight=16dip`

2) Added 16px*16px star drawables.

It changed icon, but the problem is that my stars looks blur, i.e low resolution. And I know why, bcs drawables are 16*16px, but I cant make their qualitity better (for example 76px*76px), bcs Android won't scale a rating bar icons. When you decrease the minHeight and maxHeight android will always crop the icons. Even if I dont use min and max heght result is the same - my big drawables (I tried to add drawable in hdpi,xhdpi folders) just crop.

Is there a way how to increase resolution of my drawables in custom RatingBar? Thx.

P.S. here is my code just in case:

Style:

```
<style name="CustomRatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/rating_bar_drawable</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">16dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">16dip</item>
</style>
```

rating_bar_drawable.xml:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@android:id/background" android:drawable="@drawable/car_washes_star_empty" />
<item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress" android:drawable="@drawable/car_washes_star_fill" />
<item android:id="@android:id/progress" android:drawable="@drawable/car_washes_star_fill" />
```

main.xml:

```
 <RatingBar
            android:id="@+id/car_washes_list_item_rating_bar"
            style="@style/CustomRatingBar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/car_washes_item_rating_bar_margin_right"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/car_washes_item_rating_bar_margin_right"
            android:numStars="5"/>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the star images of the RatingBar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/607610/how-to-change-the-star-images-of-the-ratingbar)

Comment: no, it is not, I changed drawables, but they are low quality

Answer (score 3):

i also tried to use the custom rating style once in android and my experience was bad so i learnt that it is better to use the native sytles and then cutomize the color in your class file as below

```
 <RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:isIndicator="false"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="1.0"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayoutLoginFailed"
    android:progressTint="@android:color/white"
   />
```

and in your class if you want to change the color of yoru rating stars add this code

LayerDrawable layerDrawable = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();

```
    // Unfilled star color
   DrawableCompat.setTint(DrawableCompat.wrap(layerDrawable.getDrawable(2)),
            Color.WHITE);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this example

1. Create custom_ratingbar_selector.xml in drawable and paste this code

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:id="@android:id/background"
   android:drawable="@drawable/unslected_star_icon" />

   <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
   android:drawable="@drawable/unslected_star_icon" />

   <item android:id="@android:id/progress"
   android:drawable="@drawable/slected_star_icon" />

   </layer-list>
   ```
2. use this in your layout activity

   ```
   <RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="21dp"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_ratingbar_selector"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="1"
    android:rating="3.0" />
   ```

   ## Note:

   my pic's dimen is 22*21 so i take height of rating bar is 21dp....check ur pic's size and set as height if u dont want to displays unaccurately

Comment: It shows single star only